# how to install discord lib on debian server (websocket error)

Tags: python, pip, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

i tried to install the discord lib on my external debian server with

> `python3 -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git`

the return is:

> `[...]`
>
> ```
> Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oq4dl632/websockets
> ```
>
> `Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log`

Full Output:

```
Downloading/unpacking git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git
  Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git to /tmp/pip-vu76dg6y-build
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-vu76dg6y-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git
    /usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    /usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)

Downloading/unpacking aiohttp>=3.6.0,<3.7.0 (from discord.py==1.4.0a2308-ge473f3c)
  Downloading aiohttp-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (441kB): 441kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking websockets>=6.0,!=7.0,!=8.0,!=8.0.1,<9.0 (from discord.py==1.4.0a2308-ge473f3c)
  Downloading websockets-8.1.tar.gz (58kB): 58kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-ayxt1lcn/websockets/setup.py) egg_info for package websockets
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ayxt1lcn/websockets/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        long_description = (root_dir / 'README.rst').read_text(encoding='utf-8')
    AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-ayxt1lcn/websockets/setup.py", line 12, in <module>

    long_description = (root_dir / 'README.rst').read_text(encoding='utf-8')

AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ayxt1lcn/websockets
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

if i tried to install the websockets (https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) i get this return:

> `[...]`
>
> ```
> Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-d5s2p_/websockets
> ```
>
> `Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log`

the `pip.log` returns:

> `Skipping (...) because it is not compatible with this Python`

so how can i install this?

Comment: And what is in the log `/root/.pip/pip.log`?

Comment: The code 1 error is just an indicator that there was a problem, so it's difficult using only this to do anything to debug the issue.  You may be able to see more details on the failure in the debug log file indicated to give you a better idea of what failed, where.

Comment: ok thx so... 

Skipping (...) because it is not compatible with this Python

Comment: What if you use `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: @AdamTL pip3  ...Pythonversion 3.8

Comment: Please show the full output of the `python3 -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git` command. Don't leave something out with `[...]`

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have provided the full error message, it becomes clear that you are using python version 3.4 for the installation:

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py    #This is one line from your error
```

But `aiohttp` has a minimum required version of python 3.5, as you can also see in [this github issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2741) (which was for me the second result in google when I entered your error `'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'`)

You have tagged python 3.8 however, so you should check your setup, since `python3` does not seem to be calling the python version you think it is calling